# After upgrading to Neo4j 3.2 all my HTTP Transactional API queries fail

Tags: neo4j

Is 3.2 an API-Breaking Release?
No. Minor releases are a place to deprecate features and functionality, which includes public APIs. However, we will not remove deprecated functionality until a major release.

Upgrading my DB from 3.1.5 to 3.2 is successful, but almost every HTTP API query from my app to Neo4j fails.

E.g.:

> 2017-06-11 12:01:20.808+0000 ERROR Failed to generate JSON output. Can
>   not start an object, expecting field name mmneo_1       |
>   org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException: Can not start an object,
>   expecting field name

And on a successful query, the result returned is not the result of the query, but a warning from the planner:

```
&{200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Access-Control-Allow-Origin:[*] Retry-Count:[0] Server:[Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)] Date:[Sun, 11 Jun 2017 12:01:20 GMT] Content-Type:[application/json]] {{"results":[{"columns":["newSession"],"data":[]}],"notifications":[{"code":"Neo.ClientNotification.Statement.PlannerUnavailableWarning","severity":"WARNING","title":"The RULE planner is not available in the current CYPHER version, the query has been run by an older CYPHER version.","description":"CREATE UNIQUE is unsupported for current CYPHER version, the query has been execute by an older CYPHER version","position":{"offset":100,"line":4,"column":1}}],"errors":[]}} -1 [] true false map[] 0xc420234300 <nil>} {"results":[{"columns":["newSession"],"data":[]}],"notifications":[{"code":"Neo.ClientNotification.Statement.PlannerUnavailableWarning","severity":"WARNING","title":"The RULE planner is not available in the current CYPHER version, the query has been run by an older CYPHER version.","description":"CREATE UNIQUE is unsupported for current CYPHER version, the query has been execute by an older CYPHER version","position":{"offset":100,"line":4,"column":1}}],"errors":[]}
```

IMO, the release notes, and *especially* the upgrade notes are sad and basically a circular reference.

I am sure it is something stupid, but honestly, I expected it to just work. How silly of me?

Answer (score 3):

The RULE planner is no longer being used with 3.2 Cypher queries. `start` and `create unique` are two clauses which rely on the RULE planner.

Either remove these from your queries (use MERGE instead of CREATE UNIQUE), or prepend your CYPHER with `CYPHER 3.1`.

EDIT

...That said, version 3.2.x should be falling back to the RULE planner and version 3.1 of the planner for these types of queries automatically (there were issues with this in 3.2.0, though I'm not sure if the problem was the browser or something deeper). From your description, it looks like that's happening, but the error isn't very friendly with respect to the expected output. I'd recommend creating an issue for this on [GitHub](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues).

Comment: yes. but I was expecting fallback as suggested by release notes. If I have to go thru and change my queries, or prepend CYPHER 3.1 it is a breaking change. I am OK with 3.2 having breaking changes assuming that Neo4j is NOT using semantic versioning. I just don't want them to tell me that there are no breaking changes when in fact, without changes my code goes to hell

Comment: Have you tried with 3.2.1? I believe there were some bugs directly related to fallback on the RULE planner in 3.2.0.